# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El mapeo de filtro especifica un nombre desconocido de filtro struts2

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, struts2, servlet-filters, illegalargumentexception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El mapeo de filtro especifica un nombre desconocido de filtro struts2
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3040)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3005)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1346)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
```

What's the problem? I am using an Apache Tomcat 7 and following 3 jars are used: -bootstrap.jar, -tomcat-juli.jar and -JRE System Library[jre7]. Is an another JAR missing? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localized logs: **NEVER** a good choice.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El mapeo de filtro especifica un nombre desconocido de filtro struts2

aka

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name struts2

is telling you that the problem is in your Struts filter configuration in `web.xml`, most likely your `<filter-name>` specified in `<filter>` is different from the `<filter-name>` specified in `<filter-mapping>`.

To fix it, use the following configuration in your web.xml :

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```